# Поиск строки с наибольшим количеством совпадений

Tags: sql, sphinx

Имеется ли в сфинксе (`SphinxQL`) какое-то решение, которое позволяет сортировать выдачу по большему количеству совпадений?
К примеру, я ищу слово `bro`, мне необходимо чтобы строки с большим количеством слова `bro` были первыми и по убыванию  (чем меньше тем
ниже).

Comment: Ну так и сортируйте сперва по количеству вхождений, а потом по релевантности. `ORDER BY LENGTH(txt)-LENGTH(REPLACE(txt,'bro','')) DESC, relevance DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть, называется SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT (в понятиях sphinxapi) или ranker=wordcount (через sphinxql, что вам и нужно).
Вот дока по ранкерам на нашем сайте: http://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/searching/search_results_ranking.html?highlight=sph_rank_wordcount
Вот по option в sphinxql - http://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/sphinxql_reference/select_syntax.html#select-option

Вот пример:

```
mysql> select * from idx_min where match('abc') option ranker=wordcount;
+------+-------------+
| id   | body        |
+------+-------------+
|    3 | abc abc abc |
|    1 | abc adc def |
|    2 | bc abc      |
+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: требуется раскрытие -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: In case my Russian isn't up to scratch, and it would appear you know English based on the fact the linked post is in English  - if you link to your own site you *must disclose the fact in the answer itself*. Here's the English version of that link above if you want -> https://en.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion